# url rewrites removing folders .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, url, url-rewriting

I want to remove 'articles' and 'artificial'  folders from a site's urls, but when I try to introduce rewrite rules into .htaccess file I am receiving errors.

http://www.example.com/articles/artificial/are_string_beans_all_right_on_the_candida_diet.php

trying to convert

http://www.example.com/are_string_beans_all_right_on_the_candida_diet.php

here is the current version of my .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!articles/artificial).*)$ articles/artificial/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be on the last rule: what you need is a **negative look behind** ie *anything not preceede with articles/artificial*

The regex should be:

```
((?<!(articles/artificial)).*)
```

But this probabilly does not work since the .* is variable length (see [regex look arrounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html))

A solution could be replacing the negative look behind with a positive look ahead that allows for variable length. So your rule could be:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?articles/artificial.*?)(.*)$ /articles/artificial/$1
```